# how to delete a row from gridview, not from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView with columns "Item Code, Name, Quantity, Rate". I bind the values for this columns from textboxes, not from database. It means I am adding values to GridView at runtime. Then in button click or in rowdeleting event, I want to delete selected row from GridView at runtime. Would you please provide solution for this? Thanks in advance...

Comment: How you add rows in gridview?

Comment: You don't have a database, but do you have any data source? a collection maybe? Can you delete from this collection?

Comment: Set the row's visible property to false `Gridview1.rows[i].visible = false;`

Comment: actually i am adding values from text boxes to datatable.then from datatable ,i am adding values to rows in gridview.It means datatable is datasource.Then after adding 3 or 4 rows,i want to delete selected rows before submitting to database.Normal delete method is not working.please help

Comment: my suggestion to you is to leave out "database" from your question. If you don't have database, don't mention it at all!

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR ANSWERS.I GOT THE ANSWER AND SPECIAL THANKS TO AMIRAM kORACH